# How to keep upstart installed-always, don't be replaced by sysvinit?

Tags: debian, package-management, upstart

Each time I do `apt-get dist-upgrade`, the package `sysvinit` comes back and replaced `upstart`. Well, I have some scripts written for upstart, and I need to reinstall it every time (typing the annoying confirmation `Yes, do as I say!`) How can I flag it as a solid rock choice, so it won't be replaced forever?

Comment: as noted in Gilles' answer, this is impossible. It's a problem for systemd too: see https://wiki.debian.org/systemd#Known_Issues_and_Workarounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is filed as Debian [bug #525141](http://bugs.debian.org/525141) (against `upstart`) and [bug #561627](http://bugs.debian.org/561627) (against `sysvinit`).

Arno Schuring notes that as a workaround, you can use `aptitude full-upgrade` instead of `apt-get dist-upgrade` (the two commands are synonyms, but aptitude tends to be a bit better at dependency management).